# Is there a listing of the recent changes made only to Gaming?

Tags: support, tags, design

I'm curious about recent changes made to Gaming after [this question](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3256/why-are-questions-adding-the-top-two-tags-to-the-title) was asked. Is there (or can there be? I didn't find anything through search) a meta post with a listing of recent changes (code, design, tags, others) made only to Gaming?

There is a post on Meta.SE which is about network wide changes:
[Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange). Just curious if there could be one specific to Gaming. Understandable if there can't be (or you don't want to) but I would think some people would be interested in seeing what changes were made, even minor.

Comment: And while we're at it, which tags got nuked? Not synonymized or merged (there's viewable records of those), but flat out *removed*. I know `Game-Mechanics` and `Murder`. Were there any others?

Comment: @RavenDreamer added a note about that in there, tags would be helpful to know. Feel free to edit it further if you'd like.

Comment: Related: [A personal appeal to Jeff Atwood: Recent Changes to Gaming](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3302/28182)

Answer (score 5):

The following tags are the ones I know have been removed. These were cleared off silently due to their incredible volume, which otherwise would've disabled the site for extended periods of time were they done manually.

- [murder](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/murder)
- [strategy](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/strategy)
- [game-mechanics](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-mechanics)
- [murder](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/murder)
- [how-to](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/how-to)
- [tips](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tips)
- [murder](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/murder)
- [tactics](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tactics)
- [curse-you-tag-limit](/questions/tagged/curse-you-tag-limit)

These were the big ones that were hit. As well, several mergers were made, such as [bug](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug) -> [technical-support](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technical-support) and [tv](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tv) -> [monitor](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monitor).

Due to the whole lack of said tags remaining, which problem tags were destroyed is a bit of a difficult thing to find.

Comment: Murder was so disliked, it was nuked twice, eh?

Comment: @JasonBerkan Three times.  It doesn't exactly stand out, does it :P.  Grace, any reason `[bug]` wasn't synonymized?

Comment: @Matthew No idea, I thought it was grabbed amidst a bunch of others that were grabbed, namely "freeze", "error", and "crash".

Comment: Bug appears to have been completely removed. Why on earth? Technical-Support's tag wiki talks about trouble installing or running a game. Few of the bug-related questions we've had had to do with installing, so I agree it's not a synonym, but what about the tag merited deletion?

Comment: @Raven Some channels were mixed. Running a game includes while it's still playing - freeze, error, and crash are all mid-game issues as often as they are start-of-game issues. While it appears that it wasn't merged as I thought, it probably still fits under the purview of [technical-support] and we can always improve the tag wiki if it is felt to be unclear.

Comment: While we're at this, can we nuke [tag:old-games] and [tag:retro-gaming] on the basis of subjectivity? What is considered a "retro" and "old" game is going to change 5-10 years from now, when we'll hopefully have dominated the internet for Gaming Q&A/still exist.

Comment: @GraceNote there are plenty of bugs that have nothing to do with tech support. Broken quests, exploitable mechanics, minus worlds, and other sorts of fun would all fall into the **Bug** umbrella without being support questions - and it meats every criteria you've cited for a good semi-dependent tag.

Comment: [meta-tag:curse-you-tag-limit] is gone now? Awww....