# Change the title when the two most popular tags share a common prefix / substring

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

As seen in [this discussion](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4538/122), the community seems to look favorably at tags in the form of [gamename-suffix], e.g. [diablo-3-demon-hunter](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diablo-3-demon-hunter). Unfortunately, as [Mark pointed out](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4543/122), this does not really sit well our [use-the-two-most-popular-tags-as-title-prefix mechanism](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3258/122), because then we get titles such as `diablo 3 diablo 3 demon hunter - How long do Caltrops last?`, which is [an actual title](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/63406/how-long-do-caltrops-last).

Can we add some special case to deal with this sort of situation? Mark already had two different suggestions on how to deal with it:

> - If a tag has a stem that's equivalent to another tag, remove the stem from the tag in the  element. So, take diablo-3 and diablo-3-demon-hunter: since diablo-3 appears in diablo-3-demon-hunter, it should be removed so the  element simply begins with "diablo 3 demon hunter".
> - Alternatively, if two tags share the same stem, only show the most popular one. Would be less SEO juice, but would also be less magic in how tags are parsed.

But anything else which can solve this issue will also be welcome.

Comment: The one potential problem I see with option 1, which is otherwise superior, is that a question tagged Game-1 Game-2 Game-Series risks becoming Game 2 Series Question. Which is... Awkward, but no moreso than what we have now.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz wouldn't it become "game 1 2 series"?

Comment: Or we could just move back to having _one_ tag in the title.

Comment: @badp at which point, we have tons of questions without a game name in their <title> element thanks to stupid platform tags.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz You say that like it's *still not a problem* when things like `achievements` are involved.

Comment: Working on this now.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118280/add-method-to-expand-tags-when-used-in-the-page-title

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This has been pushed out - please let me know of any bugs you see.

Comment: Found an issue with [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/63604/does-intelligence-influence-witch-doctor-minion-damage) not keeping "diablo 3" in the title - looking at a work-around.

Comment: Which version did you implement? Dropping the tag stem on more specific tags, or only showing one tag when two tags share the same stem?

Comment: Option 2, due to other code constraints, but looking at 1 now.  Option 2 was better, since we only look at the first two tags for this purpose and questions with 3 tags (e.g. [pc] [diablo-3] [diablo-3-demon-hunter]) would then use the demon hunter tag after dropping the lone [diablo-3].

Comment: I think this change has some issues after a question has been edited - take a look at the current title of [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/63604/does-intelligence-influence-witch-doctor-minion-damage).

Comment: @Oak yeah, that was the problem question I found earlier; a fix will be pushed soon so that [diablo-3] will still be in the page title.